# How to change sign ' to ` when save data to sql server

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, character, symbols

Hi i have a field to fill up Fullname that only allow alphabet, sign '(apostrophe), sign `@` to type when I am trying using mysql, everything is okay, but when I want to send the data to another web services that use sql server.

The problem is sign ' (apostrophe)  and give me error, because in sql script, there is script like Insert into table1 values ('','')

so how to replace sign ' (apostrophe) to ` (grave accent) before save to database

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question accordingly. You need to provide us with your attempt (the code you're having issues with), example data, expected results and what results you're currently getting.

Comment: You don't. As Verim wrote - you use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) - which prevents injection and fixes this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just stumbled about an important security bug: your user input can influence your SQL Query. It's nice to see that you try to solve the problem for yourself but your solution still has problems: What happens if I send your server a malicious request with a Full name like `Hans'; DELETE * FROM users --`? This attack is called "SQL injection" and is one of the most common attacks on servers.

TL;DR: use **ALWAYS** prepared statements and you are save